# I'm not sure how to make this stack implementation dynamic

Tags: java, arrays, generics, stack

First of all, I apologise if this is a really obvious question or if I'm not looking at it correctly.
I've been instructed to "extend the stack to be dynamic". I've been given specific instructions on how to do this, namely:

- Make a new array tmp of twice the size of the current array
- Copy all elements the current array (called S in the lecture notes) into tmp
- Set S = tmp;

The block of code which should do this is to be placed into the push() method, replacing the exception throw section.

The problem is, I have no idea what kind of array I should be using (generics have only recently introduced to me and I don't quite understand them as much as I think I should).
Is there something obvious I'm missing or do I just not understand this properly?

I didn't write the majority of this code, only the pop(), push() and top() methods.

```
public class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E> {
private E[] S;
private int top;
private int capacity;

private static int DEFAULT_SIZE = 100;

public ArrayStack(int size){
    capacity = size;
    S = (E[]) new Object[size];
    top = -1;
}

public ArrayStack(){
    this(DEFAULT_SIZE);
}


public E pop() throws StackException{
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new StackException("stack is empty");
    return S[top--];
}



public void push(E e) throws StackException{
    if (size() == capacity)
        throw new StackException("Stack is full");
    S[++top] = e;
}



public E top() throws StackException{
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new StackException("Stack is empty");
    return S[top];



}
```

Comment: What does "dynamic" mean in this case? Does it mean allowing the underlying array to expand in size when full / as needed?

Comment: I think that basically what I'm being asked to do is to double the size of the underlying array whenever something is pushed onto the stack, then transfer the contents of the current array into the new one - it's a horrible solution but I am only a beginner in Java.

Comment: That's not a terrible solution- its how most ordered data structures work. When the internal array is full, it expands by a certain factor (double is fine) then the old data is copied into the new array.

Comment: Oh, I just thought it would't be a great way to do things because (by my understanding) twice as much memory is being allocated for the array every time something is pushed onto the stack. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it appears that the array should be of `E` objects.

Using Java Generics, you can create this array with `(E[]) new Object[2 * initial_size]`

The instructions want you to look at the code segment below in push

```
if (size() == capacity)
        throw new StackException("Stack is full");
```

and without giving too much away as this is an assignment to do

```
if (size() == capacity)
       Make a new array tmp of twice the size of the current array
       Copy all elements the current array (called S in the lecture notes) into tmp
       S = tmp;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer- I tried creating a new array of E objects using `tmp = new E[size*2];` on the line after push() begins, but I'm being given 3 errors by Eclipse - it cannot create a generic array of E, and tmp and size cannot be resolved to variables. What would the correct syntax be?

Comment: @Chewy `(E[]) new Object[size*2]`

Comment: I apologise, but I'm still not getting it - I'm bombarded with errors when I try to use `(E[]) new Object[size*2]`. I know there's something really obvious I must be missing here but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I believe the "size" in your situation may be "private int capacity" as that is the name of your class field. However, be sure to update the field's value to 2x the size as creating your new array.

Comment: @Chewy: you should get unchecked cast *warnings*, not errors

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I checked things over with my lecturer and he pretty much explained to me exactly what you've been trying to tell me! I appreciate the input, hopefully I'll get better and this won't be an issue again :)